# using find and cat command for merging text files orderly

Tags: scripts, find, cat

I have a main directory and its sub-directories as;

main_directory == main_directory

0001 0102 0203 ... == first order sub_directories

001 002 003 ... == second order sub_directories

I use below command to merge all data.txt files in the second order sub_directories

```
find path_to_main_directory -name '*data.txt' -exec cat {} + > data_all
```

However, I see that `data_all` file doesn't seem orderly, such as (which I want); 0001/001+0001/002+.... it seems that the order is random.

Is there a way to merge all files orderly?

Comment: Use `find . -name '*data.txt'  -print0 | sort -z | xargs -0 cat > data_all`

Comment: Why do you use `find` in the first place? Doesn’t `cat path_to_main_dir/*/*/*data.txt >data_all` sort as needed?

Comment: @dessert it may fail if the argument list is too long - but there are ways around that e.g. `printf '%s\0' path_to_main_dir/*/*/*data.txt | xargs -0 cat`